# Basic user mapping is failing in astronvim

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to swap the functionality of the `t` and `k` key in astronvim, but find some unexpected behavior.

Basically, I want to get the same result as when running `:noremap k t` and `:noremap t k` in the command prompt in neovim. This works without any issue, but I want to have it in my config.

I've cloned `https://github.com/AstroNvim/user_example`, and changed the `user/mappings.lua` file to:

```lua
return {
  [""] = {
    ["t"] = {"k", desc = "Move up"},
    ["k"] = {"t", desc = "Till"},
  },
}
```

This does not work; `t` moves up, but `k` **also moves up**.

I have no idea why this is the case; looking at other people's `mappings.lua` does not give me any clues either.

**Any hints are greatly appreciated**

---

Additional observations:

- If I reverse the order of the two lines, the behavior is the same: both move the cursor up.
- I've tried adding the `remap=false` to each table, but the behavior is still unchanged.
- When I change the mode key from `[""]` to `["n"]` (or `n`), the behavior is different from what I described above. In that case, pressing `k` gives an error (`undefined variable: t`). It's unclear to me, why the behavior would be different at all (if I'm in normal mode), and I also do not understand this error message.

Answer (score 1):

There might be an issue with the way you've defined your mappings in the mappings.lua file. When you swap the functionality of the "t" and "k" keys, it creates a loop, where "t" is mapped to "k" and "k" is mapped to "t", so pressing either key results in the same action.

To fix this, you can use a temporary variable to avoid the loop, like so

```
    return {
  ["n"] = {
    ["t"] = {":normal! k<CR>", desc = "Move up"},
    ["k"] = {":normal! t<CR>", desc = "Till"},
  },
}
```

This configuration maps the "t" key to execute the normal mode command "k" and the "k" key to execute the normal mode command "t". By using the :normal! command, you can avoid the recursive issue.

Regarding the error message you received when using ["n"] as the mode key, it's because the mappings are applied in normal mode only. When you press "k", it looks for the "t" variable, which doesn't exist. Using the :normal! command in the updated configuration should resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your comment. I also initially thought this was a recursive/chaining issue. Because the config allows for the `remap=false` option, however, I would expect this to solve the issue, yet it also does not.

On the `[""]` vs `["n"]` issue: I chose `""` because I want the remapping to work in any mode. Basically, I'm trying to get the same result as when running `:noremap k t` and `:noremap t k` in the command prompt. This works without any issue, and I'm trying to find out, how to get the same behavior by tweaking the `user/mapping.lua` file

Comment: Try the following configuration:
`return {
  [""] = {
    ["t"] = {"<cmd>execute 'normal! k'<CR>", desc = "Move up", remap = false},
    ["k"] = {"<cmd>execute 'normal! t'<CR>", desc = "Till", remap = false},
  },
}`
This configuration should work across all modes without any issues. The key to solving the recursive/chaining issue is to use the remap = false option, which prevents mappings from being applied recursively. By wrapping the normal mode commands inside an execute command, the mappings are properly applied, and the remap = false option will take effect.

Answer (score -1):

No experience/understanding of AstroNvim, but I would guess you need to cache one of the values before swapping them. You're essentially saying:

```
t = k  
k = t which = k
```

You need something like:

```
_t = t  
t = k  
k = _t
```

I suppose something like this would work as well:

```
["t"], ["k"] = ["k"], ["t"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The lua script is only specifying a nested table of constants, so it's the way this table is processed by astronvim that is where my question lies. I was also suspecting a mapping loop, but I was confused by the fact that the `remap` option did not influence the result, and by the fact that changing the remapping from applying to all modes (`[""]` to only normal mode (`["n"]`) *did* influence the result. It is really mainly a (astro)nvim question than a lua question.